# After upgrading swift 2 to 3 getting error Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift3

Hi i upgrade my xcode from 7 to 8 now i am getting error  Ambiguous use of 'subscript', when m trying to iterate object.

[image]

Comment: Why not casting `data` to the right type before using it ? Also note that in Swift 3, Objective-C ids are now imported as `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a better idea of what you're passing into the function in order to access indices and values for keys. You can't subscript -index- an AnyObject unfortunately. Xcode needs more information first. Try something like this:

```
func makeDataSource(data:[[String:String]]) {

    for i in 0..< data.count {
        print(data[i]["make"]
    }
}
```

If you don't know if you can pass your data as [[String:String]] you can safely unwrap it first by doing something like this before you make your function call:

```
guard let myData = data as? [[String:String]] else {
    print("couldn't cast data as [[String:String]]")
    return
}

makeDataSource(data:myData)
```

If the above guard statement fails then I would check the object types located in your data array/dictionary. You can cast it as multiple things. For example:

```
as? [[String:String]]
as? [[Int:String]]
as? [[String:AnyObject]]
etc.......
```

You just need to match what's in there and your code should run smoothly.